# Suspicious email was not deleted on click of ribbon taskpane button

Tags: javascript, microsoft-graph-api, office365, office-addins, microsoft-graph-mail

I am creating spam report functionality for outlook addin users and I want "When a user clicks 'Report Spam,' an email will be sent to an email address" (for example, hello@codename64.com for testing, and we can change it before deploying to production).

The email will contain:

- Email Subject: 'Email Reported as SPAM'
- Email Body:
- Sender: The user clicking the button, i.e., the Outlook user.
- Suspicious Address: The sender's email address of the email being
  reported by the user.
- Attachment: The suspicious email will be sent as attach

Once the send action is executed, the suspicious email will be moved to the deleted items folder I have all done but the email is not deleted after sending new mail as report. I want that when the report has been sent the suspicious email will be moved to deleted items

```js
var settings = {
  url: "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages/" + mes,
  method: "DELETE",
  timeout: 0,
  headers: {
    Authorization: "Bearer " + token,
  },
};
```

Comment: Do you have the same problem outside of Outlook? Have you tried to execute MS Graph commands outside of Outlook?